# Dequeue function not working correctly

Tags: c, pointers, deque

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my dequeue function? It's always keeping the first value over and over, but otherwise seems to be working good. Sample output provided.

```
NODE *dequeue(NODE **queue)
    {
        if (*queue == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        NODE *pTemp = *queue;
        printf("[%d %d] -> ", pTemp->pid, pTemp->priority);
        *queue = (*queue)->next;
        return pTemp;
    }
```

[image]

Function is being called as such:

```
NODE *someQueue;
//code to add values here
for (i = 0; i < numberOfQueueItems; i++)
{
    printf("\nDequeue time.\n");
    printList("readyQ", someQueue);
    dequeue(someQueue);
}
```

Comment: The function looks correct, how are you calling it?

Comment: What’s `PROC`? Unless `PROC` is exactly the same as `NODE`, you can’t pass a `NODE*` like `someQueue` where `printList` expects a `PROC*`. `dequeue` also expects a `NODE**`, not a `NODE*`. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: @4386427 Thank you. I added the ampersand and it works right now. Do you mind explaining why? I get the ampersand is the address. So it makes sense to me why it works now, but it doesn't make sense to me why without the ampersand it starts at the second value?

Comment: @Birdman - Without the ampersand (i.e. when you passed the wrong value), your code had undefined behavior, i.e. it's impossible to know what the output would be from the C code alone. If you want to find out, you'll have to study the generated assembler code and the memory layout. I have not seen all your C code but from the parts you have posted, I also find the output a surprise. But that sometimes how undefined behavior is. ......

Comment: @Birdman .... The only thing that really made sense was that the first element stayed the same. That was because the value of `someQueue` never changed. But how it ended up so that it seemed to remove the second element is strange.

Comment: perhaps you are calling dequeue from a nested function call, so that the somequeue pointer doesn't change in the outer scope, even though the dequeue function signature is correct to allow the queue pointer to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `dequeue` correctly. It expects a double pointer to NODE but you pass a pointer to NODE

Change

```
dequeue(someQueue);
```

to

```
 dequeue(&someQueue);
```

Comment: Based on the code provided, this answer is correct.  It also means you should have been getting a compiler warning about an incorrect type passed to dequeue.  Even if they're just warnings, take them seriously, they are helpful indicators of trouble in your code.